# Symfony - Symlink to Controller to remove .php Extension from Url

Tags: apache, symfony1, nginx

Morning, I have been working on this problem for a few days and cannot resolve it.

Http Stack: nginx 1.0.4, apache 2.2.3, symfony 1.4.11

In my web directory I have a symlink to my backend controller, so I can use urls without the .php extension, for example: mysite.com/be_dev.php = mysite.com/be_dev

After some googling I noticed there are a myriad of ways to do it, but the approach I found to be the most elegant was to use the apache  with ForceType directives. Without this directive in place, when I use the symlink in the url it simply displays the php code, but when I put the ForceType directives in place it parses the php as expected.

The one problem I am having now, is that when I go through the symlink it treats the symlink as the webroot. So file are being served from /be_dev/sf/sf_web_debug/images/* vs /sf/sf_web_debug/images/*. If I go through be_dev.php then everything works as expected.

I have tried various rewrite rules to remove the /be_dev from the path so it would be served from / as mentioned above, but can't nail it down.

I am posting relevant snippets of the config files.

Thanks in advance.

### /usr/local/nginx/etc/nginx.conf

```
...
server {
     ...
     location /sf/ {
         root /home/websrc/projects/app/app1/current/framework/data/web;
     }
     ...
}
...
```

### /etc/httpd/conf/vhost.d/10_symfony.conf

```
<FilesMatch "^(fe|be)?(_dev)?$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

### /etc/httpd/conf/vhost.d/999_default.conf

```
Listen 3001
NameVirtualHost localhost:3001

<VirtualHost localhost:3001>

    SetEnv SERVICECLASS dev
    SetEnv SERVICEAPP   app1

    ServerName     myhost.*.mydomain.lan
    ServerAlias    myhost.*.mydomain.com    

    ServerAdmin systems@mydomain.com

    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/%2/projects/app/app1/current/code/web

    <Directory "/home/*/projects/app/app1/current/code/web">
        AllowOverride none
        Options FollowSymLinks

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteOptions inherit

        #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/be_dev/.* [NC]
        #RewriteRule ^/be_dev/(.*) /$1 [L,NC,PT]
        #RewriteRule be_dev$ /$1 [L]        

        ######
        # Symfony rules
        ######

        # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
        # getting no_script_name to work
        #RewriteBase /

        # we skip all files with .something
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
        RewriteRule .* - [L]

        # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
        RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
        RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

        # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

        RewriteRule /^(be_dev)$ /$1.php [L]
        ######
    </Directory>

    LogLevel debug
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/app1.dev.access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/app1.dev.error.log
    RewriteLog /var/log/httpd/app1.dev.rewrite.log
    RewriteLogLevel 9

</VirtualHost>
```

Update @ 6.13.2011
Still no luck in figuring this one out, any help is appreciated.

Update @ 6.15.2011
Finally got it! Posted on my blog @ http://melikedev.com/2011/06/15/symfony-remove-php-from-controller-using-symlink/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out the reason why I couldn't remove the .php from controller, after some digging around I found that I had to override a 'request' setting in the /apps//config/factories.yml file. The full answer can be found on my blog @ http://melikedev.com/2011/06/15/symfony-remove-php-from-controller-using-symlink/, the short  answer is given below.

```
# /path/to/symfony/apps/<app>/config/factories.yml

# If you don't already have the following activated you will need to make sure it's active under the 'all' directive

all:

...

request:
  class: sfWebRequest # if you are using custom class be sure to replace this with your custom class name
  param:
    logging:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
    path_info_array:&nbsp;&nbsp; SERVER
    path_info_key:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; PATH_INFO
    relative_url_root: "" # <---This is what I needed to add

...
```